# Can I skip generate html and update a component in JSF Render Response Phase?

Tags: jsf

For example I have a `commandButton` as below:

```
<p:commandButton
    actionListener="#{logicBean.doSomething}"
    update="component1 component2 component3"
/>
```

So, is it possible to skip re-generate and render `component3` from `logicBean.doSomething` method? It means that there is no new HTML for `component3` in the returned response.

I already tried `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().remove("component3");` but it does not work.

Comment: What's the actual contents of `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds()`? Did it indeed contain a `String` which exactly matches `"component3"`?

Comment: Hi @BalusC, yes it will return a list containing "component3".

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update out of the bean:

```
public void doSomething() {
  /* do the stuff */
  if(haveToDo)
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update( "component3" )
    // with older primefaces
    // RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update( "component3" );
}
```

but you have to look for the full id. It may be "tab2:myform:component3"

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that there is a misunderstanding here. I would like to remove "component3" from the render response phase.

Comment: Yes, don't write it in the html, but add it from the bean whenever you want.